# How to save objects from images true to size (not as rectagular image...)?

Tags: image, svg, png, jpeg

my question belongs to the field of image processing.

I would like to create an image file that only contains the actual content of the image. Typically, images are rectangular in shape with a fixed height and width.

How can I create an image that has the exact shape of the content it contains, without, for example, superfluous transparent areas at the edge.

What is the correct name for such pictures?

Usally i work with GIMP.
Thx a lot.

Comment: You can't. You could either create a rectangular image with transparent pixels so it appears to be the shape you want or use a rectangular image and clip it with a clip-path to the shape you want.

Comment: Don't want to vote to close; but duplicate here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743815/is-it-possible-to-create-a-circular-or-any-other-non-rectangular-image